# Set metabox color picker default to 'none' instead of '#191919' in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, color-picker, meta-boxes

My WordPress theme has a really annoying colorpicker that are pre set to a specific color (#191919). I want the color picker to always be *"cleared"* by default instead - without making changes to the parent theme code.
My question is if the below is possible to change within the functions.php in my Child Theme?

So I want to set  the metabox colurpicker to “none” `'default' => ''` instad of `'default' => '#191919'`

The original code is in a file in parent theme called **metaboxes.php** and looks like this:

```
$cmb_title->add_field( array(
        'name' => __( 'Title Text Color', 'wassap' ),
        'id'   => $prefix . 'color',
        'type' => 'colorpicker',
        'default'  => '#191919'
    ) );
```

And again – what I want to do is to set the default to: `'default' => ''` with the help of funcions.php if that is possible!

Thank you